# "force:navigateToURL" inserts "?source=aloha" in the URL which breaks page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, url, navigation

My Lightning Component app uses navigateToURL to allow lightning users (in a browser) to edit data in custom objects:

```
navigateToEdit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var articleId = cmp.get("v.articleId");
    var urlMain = '/one/one.app#/n/salesCenter_Edit_Article?id=';
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
         "url": urlMain + articleId
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

While processing this, Salesforce *inconsistently* inserts "?source=aloha" into the URL, and as a result, the page won't load the record.  If I manually take the "?source=aloha" out, the page loads the record as expected.

Comment: Perhaps related to [Query Parameters are not visible in browser url, Lightning mode, when VisualForcePage is opened](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000IA71QAG).

Comment: Unfortunately no, the issue isn't the visibility or accessibility of the URL and querystring, the issue is that SF inserts "?source=aloha" into the URL and when it does, somehow the page breaks

Comment: OK. Please add the URL that breaks the page and explain how the page is broken and perhaps include the relevant parts of the page's controller in the question.

Comment: This URL doesn't work: https://tim--timdev.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?source=aloha#/n/salesCenter_Edit_Article?id=a0WO0000006XtZbMAK  If I take out the "?source=aloha" it works:  https://tim--timdev.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/n/salesCenter_Edit_Article?id=a0WO0000006XtZbMAK

Comment: @KeithC When the first URL is used (and the page is broken), there is no data loaded.  When the second URL is used, the page loads with the data.

Comment: Nobody knows what this is?

Answer (score 0):

As @Keith C mentioned, related to the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000IA71QAG) he posted, you would have to create Publisher Actions/Quick Actions to replicate the functionality in lightning since:

As stated in the release notes of [Spring 16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_url_button_support_lex.htm)

> If you use URL custom buttons to pass parameters to standard pages in
>   Salesforce Classic—such as pre-populating fields when creating a
>   record—this behavior doesn’t work in Salesforce1 or Lightning
>   Experience.

you might want to do [object specific actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview_object_specific.htm&language=en_US&type=0) rather than try and do url hacks which are not supported.